# Django 'float' object has no attribute 'user' while using login decorator

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to build a django app and the app works, great so far.
Right now i'm in the middle of making sure the user needs a login so they can log in.
if the user is logged in than the user can use an machine-learning model to solve a problem.

The error message I'm getting is **'float' object has no attribute 'user'** and this started after I used the `@login_required` function in django.

**NOTE:** The user is login in via the `localhost:8000/admin/` panel Django provides.
(later I will change that) after I fix this bug

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
return render(request, 'home.html')

@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')


@login_required
def getPredictions(temp_normal, hour,hour_x,hour_y):
    import pickle
    model = pickle.load(open("test_model.sav", "rb"))
    prediction = model.predict([[temp_normal, hour,hour_x,hour_y]])
    return prediction



@login_required
def result(request):
    temp_normal = float(request.GET['temp_normal'])
    hour = float(request.GET['hour'])
    hour_x = float(request.GET['hour_x'])
    hour_y = float(request.GET['hour_y'])
    result = getPredictions(temp_normal, hour,hour_x,hour_y)

    return render(request, 'result.html', {'result': result})
```

**html code**
**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="card card-tasks">
          <h1> </h1>
          <form action="{% url 'result' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <p>temp_normal:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="temp_normal">
            <br>

            <p>Weging:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Weging">
            <br>

            <p>str:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="straling">
            <br>

            <p>hour:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hour">
            <br>

            <p>hour_x:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hour_x">
            <br>

            <p>hour_y:</p>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="hour_y">
            <br>

            <input class="form-control" type="submit" value='Bereken'>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**results.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Prediction</h1>

    {{ result }}
  <p>resultaat</p>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the decorator `login_required` is just for views and expects a request object as first param, thats why the error, `getPredictions` is not a view is just a function. remove the decorator `login_required` to `getPredictions` and will work.